# How can I add text to PowerPoint master using PowerPoint Add-in? (Office.js)

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js

How can I add text to PowerPoint master using PowerPoint Add-in? (Office.js)

The documented mechanism for interacting with the deck appears to be too generic for this functionality:
    `Office.context.document.*`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/powerpoint-quickstart?tabs=visual-studio

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has robust Add-In capabilities for some Office apps such as Excel and Word, but they have not released equivalent APIs for PowerPoint yet. So, editing PowerPoint text only using Office.js is not yet possible.
We had similar needs. We had to supplement Office.js with OpenXML manipulation (mostly server-side) for our Excel-to-PowerPoint add-in.